# In Drupal does content and node refers to new page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8

I am new to Drupal. I've confusion between content and nodes. Can we say always content and node refers to new page?

Answer (score 1):

> All content on a Drupal website is stored and treated as "nodes". A node is any piece of individual content, such as a page, poll, article, forum topic, or a blog entry. Comments are not stored as nodes but are always connected to one. Treating all content as nodes allows the flexibility to create new types of content. It also allows you to painlessly apply new features or changes to all content of one type.

A page is always a node, but not all nodes are pages.

Source: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/node/about-nodes